# sed, starting a new line in middle of text

Tags: sed, newline, fasta

I need to insert a new line at the start of the DNA nucleotide sequence (a,c,g,t) that occurs in the middle of the line in this txt file. I am trying to do this using sed. The line should be inserted after the header, which has multiple identifiers separated by commas and underscores and always ending with a number. acgt sequence lengths vary.

PROGRAM:sed  PROJECT:text_cmds-84

Example:

```
>AK353574,morex_contig_45194_1,474_0agtaacgctgtaatcaatgttgtgaataagacagtctgattcaacatgacatc
>AK353574,morex_contig_45194_1,474_118tgactcaactgtaatatctactgaagaactgaagggcgttagcaggatatgta
>AK353574,morex_contig_45194_1,474_236attcaggcaatgtaggcacaaaagtttccttgaggccgcaaaaaccatcttag
```

Desired output:

```
>AK353574,morex_contig_45194_1,474_0
agtaacgctgtaatcaatgttgtgaataagacagtctgattcaacatgacatc
>AK353574,morex_contig_45194_1,474_118
tgactcaactgtaatatctactgaagaactgaagggcgttagcaggatatgta
>AK353574,morex_contig_45194_1,474_236
attcaggcaatgtaggcacaaaagtttccttgaggccgcaaaaaccatcttag
```

Comment: Is the question how to insert the newline or how to match the data you have?

Comment: Do you want to break the first line too?

Comment: Question is how to insert the new line.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed, possible other seds too):

```
sed 'G;s/\(.*[0-9]\)\(.*\)\(.\)$/\1\3\2/' file
```

Append a newline, then using pattern matching and backreferences insert the newline before the nucleotides sequences.

Comment: This did not change the file. I must not have the right sed

Comment: @dmw_phylogenomics a common mistake is to think that sed edits the file by default. It does not. It copies the file and edits the copy. To edit the file there is an option `-i`. Behind the scenes this: edits a temporary file then renames it the orginal file name. The `-i` can also have a parameter which is used to make a backup of the original file.

Answer (score 0):

Posix:

```
sed 's/.*_[0-9]\{1,\}/&\
/' YourFile
```

GNU:

```
sed 's/.*_[0-9]+/&\n/' YourFile
```

using the behavior of sed that try to always take the biggest parttern from the left

Comment: With Unix text breaks, neither of these scripts worked with my sed version.

Comment: what do you mean by *unix text breaks* ? works on my AIX and linux from your sample data

Comment: I am working on a mac. When I chose to import the fasta and save it again, using the text edit program, it gave me several options for how to code the _text breaks_. When I chose Unix, it worked.

Comment: ok, you should in this case add the FormFeed character after the new line (`/f`) see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-sed-ascii-control-codes-nonprintable/